# How to create an array in JavaScript whose indexing starts at 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

By default the indexing of every JavaScript array starts from 0. I want to create an array whose indexing starts from 1 instead.

I know, must be very trivial... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I ask because when you find yourself trying to circumvent one of the most basic characteristics of a programming language, odds are good there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: And besides, starting array indices from 0 is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: If you want to display indices to a user you can just display i + 1. You really should just get used to zero indexes because you are going to run into so many fence-post errors in your lifetime if you work around it.

Comment: If you want it so badly, then you can create your own data structure. Something like `singlyLikedList`, and modify its methods.

Comment: Maybe OP wanted to check if the value of index exists in order to execute something. Instead of making it start at 1, you can just do this: `if(i !== false)`

Comment: An array starting at 1 is not treated as an array in JS, its treated as an object.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It isn't trivial. It's impossible. The best you could do is create an object using numeric properties starting at 1 but that's not the same thing.

Why exactly do you want it to start at 1? Either:

- Start at 0 and adjust your indices as necessary; or
- Start at 0 and just ignore index 0 (ie only use indices 1 and up).

Comment: Impossible...dats surprising! Well, there's no useful reason for me to say...why I want to start at 1...just an idea. So, yeah..i guess, I have to adjust my indices accordingly, which is not a problem.
Wanted to start at 1, just for the sake of it.

Comment: Now, 8 years later, you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: How do I ignore index 0 in Javascript?

Comment: @josefdev - put a value there, and then never refer to it. I.E. `a = ["ignore me", "this has index 1", "another string, at index 2"];  firstString = a[1];` However, this advice isn't very useful - built in functions such as `for (s of a)` won't 'know' that you want to ignore `a[0]` - the burden is entirely on you to find ways to code that don't use a[0]; it is more practical to get used to arrays starting at 0.

Answer (score 13):

A simple solution is to fill the zeroth item:

```
var map = [null, 'January', 'February', 'March'];
'First month : ' + map[1];
```

Semantically it would be better to use an object:

```
var map = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March'};
'First month : ' + map[1];
```

Note these keys are not ints actually, object keys are always strings.
Also, we can't use dot notation for accessing. ([MDN - Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators))

I'd choose the first solution, which I think is less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove the first element like so:

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];
delete arr[0];

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Or just not define it at all:

```js
let arr = [,'b','c'];

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

If you want to make sure that you always get the first truthy element regardless of the index and have access to ES6 you can use:

```
arr.find(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question asks "*How to create an array in JavaScript whose indexing starts at 1*". The accepted answer states "*It isn't trivial. It's impossible.*"

This is true, and should be understood for good reason. However, you can create an array and *omit setting the first element*, in which case it will still exist (hence the accepted answer being correct) but it'll be marked as empty for you.

```js
let usernames = ['bob', 'sally', 'frank']
let myArray = [];
let arrayIndex = 1;

usernames.map(username => {
    myArray[arrayIndex] = username;
    arrayIndex++;
})

console.log(myArray);
```

> Array(4) [ <1 empty slot>, "bob", "sally", "frank" ]
> 1: "bob"
> 2: "sally"
> 3: "frank"
> ​length: 4

Notice that the length is "4".

```js
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

> undefined

Using this, there's a quirk in our favour whereby using `Object.keys()` on an array doesn't return empty (undefined) elements. So with the above array:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(myArray).length);
```

> 3

Note: This is arguably a little hacky so use it with caution.

As zero of something rarely exists in our world, doing this might be useful where you are only going to access pre-defined indexes. An example would be if you have pages of a book. There isn't a page 0 as that makes no sense. And if you are always access a value directly, e.g.

```js
const currentPage = pages[1];
```

Then this is fine in my opinion, as long as the code shows intent. Some will argue that ignoring a valid array index is futile, and I don't fully disagree. However, it's also futile and very annoying when I want to get page 35 of a book and the array index is 34. Meh!

When you loop your (dodgy) array with `map` it ignores the 0 index you didn't want:

```js
myArray.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(value);
})
```

> 1
> bob
> 2
> sally
> 3
> frank

For general use however, you should use index 0, so when you loop some data and spit things out you're not going to get caught out by the first one being empty.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to @cletus you couldn't do that because it's a built-in javascript feature but you could go slightly different way if you still want that. You could write your own index-dependent functions of Array (like `reduce`, `map`, `forEach`) to start with 1. It's not a difficult task but still ask yourself: why do I need that?

```
Array.prototype.mapWithIndexOne = function(func) {
  const initial = []
  for (let i = 1; i < this.length + 1; i++) {
    initial.push(func(this[i - 1], i))
  }
  return initial
}

const array = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth']

console.log(array.mapWithIndexOne((element, index) => `${element}-${index}`))
// => ["First-1", "Second-2", "Third-3", "Fourth-4", "Fifth-5"]
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvbNZR?editors=0012

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.map`

```
[,1,2,3].map((v, i) => ++i)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not entirely sure what this is suggesting. It looks like you already have the 1-indexed array before you use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that an index in c ish languages is *also* the offset from the first element.  This allows all sorts of offset math where you don't have to subtract 1 before doing the math, only to add the 1 back later.

if you want a "1" array because the indexes are mapped to other values, that's the case for an enumeration or a hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you open devTools in Chrome (F12) and you put the following JavaScript

`arr=[,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']`

the following result is shown by the Google Chrome developer console:

[image: The result shown by Google Chrome console]

Notice that the index starts at 1, but it doesn't mean that the arr[0] item is not there: in fact it is just empty. In fact you can notice the last index that is 26 but the length is 27, so there is an array item that does not show.
You can start a for loop from i = 1 now but the array length is still different from the last index: in fact it is i+1.
Also doing arr[0] you will get as result undefined, exactly as if you do arr[27]

And also you can loop starting from i=1:

```js
arr=[,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

for(i=1; arr[i]!=undefined; i++) {console.log(i + ':' +arr[i])}
```

This could be useful sometimes to know, but the i=0 item is still there, just it isn't shown cause it is empty or undefined. And that fact is demonstrated by the length of 27 even if the index of the last array item is 26.

You get a similar result if you set as empty some other item:
[image]

Empty items are represented without a number.
But if you set an item as undefined instead, it is rendered as undefined and not as empty:

[image]

But of course you can still render the undefined if you do a loop like:

`for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {console.log(i +':'+ arr[i])}`
than you get the following result:

[image]

As you can see into the above screenshot the item i=0 is there, but it is not there the i=27

So to answer the question:
Arrays in javascript do not start from other than index = 0, but we can observe that it is possible some kind of "emulation" of such behavior, even if it is not complete real.

In VBA instead it is possible to use the "Option Base 1" declaration at the top of a code module to change the default lower bound to 1 instead of 0. But it seems that Javascript doesn't have that possibility (yet).

It is also possible to get an empty / undefined element using the delete method
let myarr = ['first','second','third','more elem'];
delete myarr[0];
now myarr is
[empty,'second','third','more elem'];
and what I said before is still valid. Look at the Chrome console:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First add this function to your javascript codes:

```
var oneArray = function(theArray)
{
    theArray.splice(0,0,null);
    return theArray
}
```

Now use it like this:

```
var myArray= oneArray(['My', 'name', 'is', 'Ram']);

alert(myArray[1]); << this line show you:   My
```

**See [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/arjf4hdu/)**

Comment: This doesn't work with many array methods. For example, `Array.from(myArray.keys())` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @Gothdo, i think you're wrong! ‌Because this result >> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` has not any unexpected value for @detj (questioner). He just need `([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])[n]` when `n>=1`.So this array always has correct result for him.

Answer (score -1):

Just prepend a `null`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.unshift(null)
a[3]    // 3
```

Answer (score -4):

Simple, just make two changes to the classic Javascript `for` loop.

```js
var Array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 1; i <= Array.length; i++) {
  //"i" starts at 1 and ends
  //after it equals "length"
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: in this way  when looping and you  have i =1 you just get 'b', not 'a'