# Is there a way to make arrays start with 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to make arrays start from "1" instead of "0"?

I am just asking this question for curiosity. Can we make a code in a editor that can do so?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826682/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-javascript-whose-index-starts-from-1)

Comment: `a = [, 1, 2, 3]; console.log(a[1]); /* 1 */ console.log(a[0]); /* undefined */`

Comment: You are free to ignore element 0, but the JavaScript runtime will maintain the `.length` of an array to include it. Thus you'd have to be careful to always recognize that, for your code, the `.length` of an array is one less than what `.length` says it is. Because that would be messy and error-prone, it's not something that an experienced programmer would do without having some very solid reason.

Comment: `var arr = [1,2,3,4]; delete arr[0]; Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr); // ["1", "2", "3", "length"]`

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to need to do this. But if you really must for some odd reason...

You can temporarily hack it by either:

```
var arr = [,ele1,ele2,ele3...]

//arr[1] = ele1;
```

However keep in mind that the length of arr is still including index 0, so the length would be 4.

or instead of using an array, use an object:

```
var obj = {1: 'ele1', 2: 'ele2', 3: 'ele3'}

//obj[1] = ele1;
```

Comment: That is not an array whose first index is 1. It is a normal array whose first *element* is null.

Comment: @str thanks for clarifying - made an edit