# Why does Array.from() return the first element undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

When I do

```
const arrayLike = { 1:'foo', 2:'bar', length:2 };
Array.from(arrayLike);
```

I get

```
[ undefined, 'foo' ]
```

When I do

```
const arrayLike = { 1:'foo', 2:'bar', length:3 };
Array.from(arrayLike)
```

I get

```
[ undefined, 'foo', 'bar' ]
```

- Why do I not see `bar` when I set the length?
- Why do I see only my elements only when I hard-set the length to 3?
- Why is the first element showing up as `undefined`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I create an array in javascript whose index starts from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2826682/6188402)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes nothing to do with array.from. that question is just challenging wanting to implement a 1-index array, not convert a 1-index object to an array.

Comment: Still related. Explains the issue of this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Array's are `0` indexed in JavaScript

All of these questions are answered pretty simply. `Array.from` assumes that the array-like object you're giving it is zero-indexed. If it isn't you'll get an array that is zero-indexed with all elements that aren't set, including `0` set to `undefined`. So in your example,

```
const arrayLike = { 1:'foo', 2:'bar', length:2 };
Array.from(arrayLike);
```

Is essentially the same as,

```
const arrayLike = { 0:undefined, 1:'foo', 2:'bar', length:2 };
Array.from(arrayLike);
```

Because the length is less than the max elements, it essentially stops iterating at that point and the false-length functions as a truncation. What you want is likely,

```
const arrayLike = { 0:'foo', 1:'bar', length:2 };
Array.from(arrayLike);
```

Or if you're getting the Array-like from a source that is 1-indexed, set `length` appropriately so as not to lose the last element, and then ditch the first element from the result (the equivalent of `shift`).

```
const arrayLike = { 1:'foo', 2:'bar', length:3 };

let arr = Array.from(arrayLike).splice(1);

let arr = Array.from(arrayLike);
arr.shift();


let [, ...arr] = Array.from(arrayLike);
```

Comment: You can display the way `Array.from` converts the object, by using the callback: `Array.from(arrayLike, (v, i) => {console.log(v, i); });`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.from(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) does not return `undefined`, it returns a *new array* using properties from a given array-like object `obj`.

And **the default values of each index position created is undefined when not given**.

The `undefined` value you are seeing is at index `0` of the created array.

Anyways, it is not a problem, you can still access the indexes `1` and `2` and they will return the values you expect them to return.

You can also verify the default behavior of created arrays with:

```js
console.log(new Array(10))
```

which logs (index positions `0..9`) (length `10`):

```
[undefined x 10]
```

In JavaScript, you will not see any array with the first index other than `0`. Independently how the array was created.

---

Another alternative to what you are doing is to set the *prototype*:

```js
const arrayLike = { 1:'foo', 7:'bar' };

//Dynamic set the length
arrayLike.length = Math.max(...Object.keys(arrayLike)) + 1;

//Get built-in features of Array to your arrayLike
Object.setPrototypeOf(arrayLike, Array.prototype);

//Do something
arrayLike.forEach((x, i) => console.log("%i: %s", i, x))
```