# angular-material2 md-paginator pageIndex of pageEvent does not make sense?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When I trigger the `onPageChange` handler, it gives me the current pageIndex.

My case is the API's first-page index is `1`, not `0`. But when I set `[pageIndex]='1'`, the paginator shows `11-20 of NaN`.

If I set `[pageIndex]='0'`, the paginator shows `1-10 of NaN`.

I expect when `[pageIndex]='1'` is set, paginator should show `1-10 of NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are meant to start from `0`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826700/5556177).

So there's nothing wrong with `md-paginator` `pageIndex`. If your backend expects page number 1 as first page, you can fix the difference by adding 1 to `pageIndex` before sending the request. Here's an example:

html:

```
<md-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              (page)="onPageChange($event)">
</md-paginator>
```

ts:

```
onPageChange(event){
    let n = event.pageIndex + 1;
    alert(JSON.stringify("Page Number to send to backend : " + n));
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LJUfHtutdEby5qWw4kH2?p=preview)