# Is there any way to change array elements indexing, so it starts 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 0, 1 ,2, 3?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexing

I don't want to move elements positions by using push()/slice()/unshift() .etc, because even if I changed the elements positions' by using one of those methods, the indexes still start from '0', not '1'.

My goal is to 'manipulate the elements **index**' so when I callback to them, it goes starting 1, 2, 3, 4 . . .

this code essentially works fine. I want to manipulate the array elements indexes :|

```js
  $(function submenuTrigger(){
    var list = [
      ["", 'Urus', 'Aventador', 'Experiences', 'Few Off', 'Concept', 'Ad Personam', "&nbsp;"], // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 6 . .
      ["", 'People', 'History', 'Masterpieces', 'Design', 'Innovation & Exellences', "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;"],
      ["", "Locators", "Accessori Origianli", "Spare Parts", "Services", "Polo Storico", "Financial Services", "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;"],
      ["", "News", "Events", "Museum", "Accademia", "Esperienza", "Lamborghini Lounge", "Mobile App", "&nbsp; "],
      ["", "News", "Events", "Museum", "Accademia", "Esperienza", "Lamborghini Lounge", "Mobile App", "&nbsp; "]
    ]
    var int_compare = 0;
    $('#home-menu-nav ul li').mouseenter(function(){
      var li_int = $(this).index() + 1; // make sure li indexes start 1, 2, 3, 4 . .
          list_int = list[li_int];      // make sure list's first elements start counting 1, 2, 3, 4 . .
          list_len = list_int.length;   // makes automatically count inside of for statement / loop_int = [list]
          int_compare = li_int;
          console.log(list_int)
          if(li_int == int_compare){
            for(p = 0; p < list_len; p++){
              console.log(list_len)
              $('#submenu-content-row-left ul li:nth-child('+ p +')').html(list[li_int - 1][p]);
              nbsp = list[li_int - 1][p]
            }
          } else {
            console.log('none');
            return
          }
    })
  })
```

```html
 
<div id="home-menu-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>MODELS</li>
    <li>BRAND</li>
    <li>OWNDERSHIP</li>
    <li>EXPERIENCE</li>
    <li>MOTORSPORT</li>
    <li>STORE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div id="submenu-content-row-left">
  <ul>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I would like to change the elements' indexes if I could

Comment: Why fight one of the most basic aspects of the language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an array in javascript whose index starts from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826682/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-javascript-whose-index-starts-from-1)

Comment: #MarkMeyer cuz it's really annoying me to add +1 or -1 every time when I put something in there.

Comment: #MohammadUsman I've read that article before upload my question. Some guy said this can be solved by using Map() method so I tried few times yesterday but it didn't work at all. Would you mind if I ask about how to use Map() method to solve my issue?

Comment: The only time you need to put a +1 is when you're showing it to the user, and a -1 when you're taking input. We just spent more time all together on this question than you will spend typing +1 and -1 if you do it a hundred times. Sometimes a bad habit in programming is spending a ton of energy in the pursuit of saving a tiny amount of effort. Those are the kinds of optimizations that make code unreadable and difficult to fix. Writing it out and following the standards makes it easy to know what's happening in your code.

Comment: You don't need to add +1 or -1 if you build around the fact that arrays start at zero. Millions of JavaScript (and c and python and java an c++, etc)  programmers manage. It is actually a lot more convenient in many situations. Here's a [good, short article](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)  from [Edsger Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) on why.

Comment: @joshstrike MarkMeyer Thank you guys for answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want to, create a `CustomArray` that inherits the prototype methods from `Array`:

```js
window.CustomArray = (function() {
  function CustomArray() {
    var customArray = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    customArray = (Array.apply(customArray, [null, ...arguments]) || customArray);
    Object.defineProperty(customArray, 'len', { 
      get: function(){ return this.length - 1 },
    });
    return (customArray);
  }
  return (CustomArray);
}).call({});

var a = new CustomArray('Urus', 'Aventador', 'Experiences', 'Few Off', 'Concept', 'Ad Personam');

console.log(a[1]);
console.log(a.len);
```

Please note that you can overwrite prototype methods on CustomArray if need be, but there's no way to override inherited properties like `length`, which is why I added `len` property which returns `length-1`. You will also have to override all iterator methods to account for the fact that the constructor adds a `null` element at index 0.

Comment: You've literally saved my day. Appreciated!

Comment: May I ask 1 more thing about what `||` is stand for inside of `. . . [null, ...arguments]) || customArray)`? I know `||` is logical operator of OR and I do understand entire code except that line.

Answer (score 2):

All arrays have a 0 element whether you want them to or not. That is the first element of the array. If you put your first element at index 1, you will still have an empty element at index 0 and you will have to skip it every time you access the array.

This is just a fundamental part of the way all modern programming languages work. When you display the element number to the user, you usually add 1 to it for human-readability purposes. Obviously if you want to achieve your goal here, you can just unshift an empty element into the array. But you will still have an empty element at 0.

Comment: 'you can just unshift an empty element into the array. But you will still have an empty element at 0.' This is my major reason why I don't use those methods.. So you mean there's no way to manipulate the indexes?

Comment: No, because in any programming language, under the hood, an "array" is an allocation of memory space. When you declare an array, you're telling the computer to reserve a big block of memory addresses that are getting mapped into this easy-to-list thing that starts at zero in your array variable. It's like a car motor. If you disconnect the wire from the distributor to the spark plug on the first cylinder, the cylinder's still there, the distributor still works, you just aren't putting a spark in it. When you allocate memory to an array, the first cylinder is called "zero". Bad analogy, maybe.

Comment: To clarify what I'm trying to say, at a very basic level, the 0 element of an array gets mapped to a memory space when you create the array whether you fill it or not. Also, if you start an array at element 3, then 0, 1 and 2 get mapped to memory even if they're empty. Objects -- like the guy below suggested -- are "sparse" meaning they do not require all the previous spaces to be filled in. But that's because they aren't numerical, they're using string keys. That makes them bad for doing anything in order, counting them or moving them around later if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

> All arrays have a 0 element whether you want them to or not.

You cannot have your array starting with 1. There are three ways to do it so it looks like it:

Option 1: Set 0 to null

```js
var myArray = {
  null,
  "item1",
  "item2"
};
document.write(myArray[1]);
```

Option 2: Use the `unshift()` function

```js
var myArray = {
  "item1",
  "item2"
};
myArray.unshift();
document.write("myArray")
```

Option 3: If you're showing the result on the page, subtract 1

```js
var myArray = {
  "item1",
  "item2"
};
var itemToAccess = 1;
itemToAccess += -1;
document.write(myArray[itemToAccess])
```