# How to start Array index value from 1 in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i want start index value from 1 not 0

```js
{props.useraccountListData.useraccountTypeList.map((item, index) => (
{index}
))}
```

The output is start from 0 1 2

But i want start from 1 2 3..

Comment: Why not just write `{index + 1}` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array in JavaScript whose indexing starts at 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826682/how-to-create-an-array-in-javascript-whose-indexing-starts-at-1)

Comment: You cannot change the way the Array.prototype methods work.

Answer (score 3):

just use `{index + 1}` inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

The index in JavaScript always starts at 0 and this cannot be changed. The only way to remedy this is to write index + 1 when you output. This assumes you wish to loop through all items.