# how to start index is start 1 not from 0

Tags: handlebars.js

We have systems that are automatically set in the backend, which is an order. `line_items` are elements. And the code is starting from zero number of each product detail. But I want to achieve it starting from 1. Here is the complete template code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

  <head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      #outlook a {
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      }

      table,
      td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
      }

      img {
        border: 0;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 100%;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
      }

      p {
        display: block;
        margin: 13px 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
        .mj-column-per-100 {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100%;
        }
      }
    </style>


    <style type="text/css">


    </style>


  </head>

  <body>


    <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:700px; padding:0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">


      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="direction:ltr;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">

              <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style=" text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="word-break:break-word; padding-bottom: 6px;">

                      <div style=" font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Сайн байна уу?</div>

                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      <div style="padding-bottom: 18px; font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">{{order.purchaser_name}} үнийн санал татаж авлаа.</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" word-break:break-word;>

                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="font-size: 13px;color:#000000;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:22px;table-layout:auto;width:100%;border:none;">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">R Дугаар</td>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black;  ">{{order.number}}</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Овог Нэр/ Байгууллагын нэр РД</td>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; ">{{order.purchaser_name}}</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Утасны дугаар</td>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; ">{{order.phone}}</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Имэйл хаяг</td>
                          <td style="padding-left:3px; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; ">{{order.email}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
          <tr align="left">
            <th style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;  border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold; width:0;">№</th>
            <th style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Барааны нэр</th>
            <th style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Нэгж үнэ</th>
            <th style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Тоо ширхэг</th>
            <th style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right:3px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">Нийт</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="character-template" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
          {{#each order.line_items as |li|}}
            <tr style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
              <td align="center" class="product-number" style=" font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                {{ @index}}
              </td>
              <td class=" product-title" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                <h5 style="font-size:13px; margin:0;">{{li.name}}</h5>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                <span class="selling-price">{{li.price}} ₮</span>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.quantity}}</td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.total}} ₮</td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}

          <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4" class="product-title" style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold; ">
              <h5 class="text-center my-1" style="font-weight: 400; font-size:13px; margin:0;">хүргэлт</h5>
            </td>

            <td class="product-title" style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
              <h5 class="text-center my-1" style="font-size:13px; margin:0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;">{{order.shipment_total}} ₮</h5>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" class="product-title" colspan="4" style="border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
              <h5 style="font-size:13px; margin:0;" class="text-center my-1 font-weight-bold">Нийт төлбөр</h5>
            </td>
            <td class="product-title" style="border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold; ">
              <h5 class="text-center my-1 font-weight-bold" style="font-size:13px; margin:0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;">{{order.item_total}} ₮</h5>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Briefly, inside here I want to have `@index` start from 1, but it actually starts from 0. How to make it 1 to start?

```
   {{#each order.line_items as |li|}}
            <tr style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
              <td align="center" class="product-number" style=" font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                {{ @index}}
              </td>
              <td class=" product-title" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                <h5 style="font-size:13px; margin:0;">{{li.name}}</h5>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
                <span class="selling-price">{{li.price}} ₮</span>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.quantity}}</td>
              <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.total}} ₮</td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
```

Here the numbers are starting like `@index` is 0, but I am trying to get `@index + 1`. Is there any solution?

Comment: add +1 to the @index values ?  

Comment: yes. I want to add 1 to the index values. The actual index value is 0.

Comment: Yes, and I ment to say change `{{ @index}}` to `{{ @index+1 }}`

Comment: I've tried it to {{@index+1}} but it does not work

Comment: I was tried    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
   <script>var Handlebars = require('handlebars');  Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options)
{
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});</script>     And then I add {{inc @index}} which was also not work. I've stuck

Comment: see: [How to create an array in JavaScript whose indexing starts at 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826682/how-to-create-an-array-in-javascript-whose-indexing-starts-at-1)

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars does not have out of the box a helper to increment an integer. However, you can easily create your own. For example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('increment', function (val) {
  return val + 1;
});
```

The above helper just adds `1` to the number you give it. You would use this helper in your template like this:

```
{{increment @index}}
```

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  order: {
    line_items: [
      {
        name: 'Line Item 1',
        price: 10,
        quantity: 2,
        total: 20
      },
      {
        name: 'Line Item 2',
        price: 5,
        quantity: 2,
        total: 10
      }
    ]
  }
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('increment', function (val) {
  return val + 1;
});

const output = template(data);

document.getElementById('Table').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table"></table>

<script id="Template" type="text/template">
  {{#each order.line_items as |li|}}
    <tr style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
      <td align="center" class="product-number" style=" font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
        {{increment @index}}
      </td>
      <td class=" product-title" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
        <h5 style="font-size:13px; margin:0;">{{li.name}}</h5>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">
        <span class="selling-price">{{li.price}} ₮</span>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.quantity}}</td>
      <td style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; font-size:13px;border-top: 1px solid black;  border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;  border-left: 1px solid black; font-weight:bold;">{{li.total}} ₮</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```